# Laravel response is the homepage on controller update method

Tags: php, laravel

I'm facing a stange behavior when I call this controller method from a Guzzle PUT on another app, Laravel response is the homepage with or without validation rules

```
public function update(Request $request, Stage $stage)
    {

        $jsonRequest = json_decode($request->all()[0]);

        /*return response()->json([
            'request' => $jsonRequest
        ]);*/

        /*$validatedData = $request->validate([
            'id'=>'required'
        ]);*/


        if($stage->update($jsonRequest)){
            return response()->json([
                'result' => 'success',
                'id' => $request->get('id'),
            ]);
        }else{
            return response()->json([
                'result' => 'error',
                'id' => $request->get('id'),
            ]);
        }

    }
```

I've checked the request is sended but I'm unable to update and having the exepected response.

Answer (score 0):

OK i've found the problem json_decode must use the associative parameter to return an array
like that

```
public function update(Request $request, Stage $stage)
    {

        $RequestArray = json_decode($request->all()[0],true);

        /*return response()->json([
            'request' => $jsonRequest
        ]);*/

        /*$validatedData = $request->validate([
            'id'=>'required'
        ]);*/


        if($stage->update($RequestArray)){
            return response()->json([
                'result' => 'success',
                'id' => $RequestArray['id'],
            ]);
        }else{
            return response()->json([
                'result' => 'error',
                'id' => $RequestArray['id'],
            ]);
        }

    }
```